# Form wont appear in admin side of website and confused as to why and wondering if someone else could see why

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

models.py

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    BookID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    BookTitle = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    UploadImage = 
    models.ImageField(upload_to='ContactImg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.BookId
```

forms.py

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    BookID=forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True)
    BookTitle=forms.CharField(max_length=30,required=True)
    Author=forms.CharField(max_length=35,required=True)
    UploadImage=forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('BookID', 'BookTitle', 'Author','UploadImage')
```

Views.py

```py
def ContactUs(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context_dict['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        context_dict['logged_in'] = False

    user_form=ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():

            # we load our profile instance

            Contact.BookId = user_form.get('BookId')
            Contact.BookTitle = user_form.get('BookTitle')
            Contact.Author= user_form.get('Author')
            Contact.UploadImage= user_form.get('UploadImage')
            Contact.save()

            return redirect('readingTime:home')

        else:
            # Invalid form
            # messages.error(request, 'Form contains errors. Double check')
            print(user_form.errors)
            messages.error(request, 'Form contains errors. Double check')
            # user_form = user_form.errors
            # user_form = RegisterForm()
    else:
        # Blank form since we do not have an HTTP POST
        user_form = ContactForm()


    return render(request,"readingTime/ContactUs.html",context=context_dict)
```

Html

```
{% extends 'readingTime/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block style_css %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/ContactUs.css' %}" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block navigation_bar %}
<div class="navigation-bar">
        <a href="/readingTime/">home</a>


        {% if logged_in %}
            <a href="/readingTime/logOut/" class="right">Sign Out</a>
            <a href="/readingTime/signIn/" class="right">My account</a>
            <a href="/polls/" class="right">User Polls</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="/readingTime/register/" class="right">Register</a>
            <a href="/readingTime/signIn/" class="right">Sign In</a>
            <a href="/readingTime/signIn/" class="right">Poll Results</a>
        {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="main" >
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<div class="main2">
    <form id="user_form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="{% url 'readingTime:ContactUs' 
   %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="contact-container">

            <h2>Request To Add A Book</h2>
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    Bookd Id (ISBN) <input type="text" name="BookID" value="" size="30" />
                    <br />
                    Book Title <input type="text" name="BookTitle" value="" size="50" />
                    <br />
                    Author(Full Name) <input type="text" name="Author" value="" size="30" />
                    <br />
                    Book Cover(Optional)<input type="file" id="UploadImage" name="UploadImage">
                    <br/>


                    <!-- Submit button-->
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Send Request</button>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </form>
<h4>Popular Questions</h4>

    <ul>

            <li> <div class="Question">How To Sign In ?</br></br>
            <Answer>Click on the sign in page button and enter your log in details</Answer></div> 
 </li>

            </br></br></br>
            <li> <div class="Question">How to edit my profile?</br></br>You need to be first signed in and then you can navigate to myAccount and click edit profile to change your details</br></div></li>

            </br></br></br>
            <li> <div class="Question">How to Sign out of my account?</br></br>You need to navigate to the sign out button at the top and press it to sign out</div></li>

            </br></br></br>
            <li> <div class="Question">How to register for an account?</br></br>Click on the register button at the top of the page in order and then enter your details or go to the sign in page and sign up to register there</div></li></ul>
            <!-- action indicates where to send the form when submitted -->


</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}

{% endblock %}
```

I am wondering as to why it wont let me send the information inside the form to admin side of the page as it lets me automaticaly a manual from into the admin side but wont let me recieve the data from the form i create for the contact us page and was wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why this is ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done this has a lot of errors.

Lets start again:

Your model looks fine.

`forms.py`:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Contact
    fields = '__all__'
```

`views.py`

```
from .forms import ContactForm

def ContactUs(request):

   if request.user.is_authenticated:
      logged_in = True
   else:
      logged_in = False

   if request.method == 'GET':
      user_form=ContactForm()

   elif request.method == 'POST':
       user_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if user_form.is_valid():
           user_form.save()
           return redirect('readingTime:home')

   context = {
      'logged_in': logged_in,
       'user_form': user_form
   }


   return render(request, "readingTime.html", context)
```

`readingTime.html`

```
<form id="user_form" class="contact-form" method="POST" action="{% url'readingTime:ContactUs'%}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="contact-container">
  <h2>Request To Add A Book</h2>
       {% csrf_token %}
         {{ user_form }}
         <!-- Submit button-->
          <div>
          <button type="submit" class="submit-button">Send Request</button>
          </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything or fix it when i use this ?

Comment: I think you forgot to load your model instance, check edited answer.

Comment: I've added this in but it still comes back with the form is not valid from my error check within the views

Comment: I think you also didn't render your form correctly in the template, check updated answer.

Comment: Yep I added that in just before you answered first but I still comes back with the form is invalid and won't display in the admin. Also sorry about the hastle just been stuck on this for ages.

Comment: Also change `class ContactForm(forms.Form):` to `class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Comment: There's quite a few errors with the code, and all of them will cause some sort of issue. I will update my answer with a better approach.

Comment: This dosent seem to solve it and it makes my form on the html page double in size and adds in extra fields to it

Comment: I still havent managed to get this working so any thoughts would be a massive help thanks

Comment: What error is your form submission giving you? It should tell you with the new form?